# Creating an array of frequencies

Tags: c++

Can someone help me with a code for the following subject ?

I have an int array of N dimension. I need to create another array and put there the frequencies of each number of the first one.
For e.g.
tab1[N] = 0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2 4 5... etc
The result must be a new array with the values : 3(since there are 3 zeros) 3(since there are 3 ones) 3 1 1...

Also, I need to use only For, While and If.

I created this code but it doesn't work.

```
int m=0;
int k = 0;
while (k<N)
{
    if (tab1[k] == tab1[k+1])
    {
       fuqi[m]++;
       k++;
    }  
    m++;
    k++;
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more then "It doesn't work"? What do you get?

Comment: After running the code, Dos stops working (end now message shows up).

Comment: I'm not sure but I think is because of value of N and tab1[k+1] !

Comment: That's a very likely guess. At least it's the source of a possible problem as you risk reading from out of bounds there.

Comment: How is `tab1` declared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find this more straight forward.

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
  fuqi[i] = 0;
}

fuqi[0] = 1;

for (int i = 1, j = 0; i < N; i++) {
  if (tab1[i - 1] == tab[i])
    ++fuqi[j];
  else 
    ++fuqi[++j];
}
```

Note that I skip checking for N == 0.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

assuming `fugi` is set to 0

```
int m=0;
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    fuqi[m]++;
    if (!(i == N - 1 || tab1[i] == tab1[i+1]))
    {
        m++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works... But what if need to get also the last value (N) ?

Comment: what do you mean "get"? it count the last one as well.